# How do you extract the year from a date using lubridate package in R?

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

Tried using ymd() function on the column reign_start but give
error as:

```
Warning: All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
[1] NA
```

The years are represented in B.C.

[image: The year is represented in B.C]

Comment: I couldn't replicate your problem. `df <- tibble(reign_start = as.Date(c("0026-01-16", "0014-09-18", "0037-03-18", "0041-01-25", "0054-01-13", "0068-06-08"))); ymd(df$reign_start)` gives me back a vector of dates. Can show the code you use, so that we can replicate your error?

Comment: `start_year <- emperors %>% 
  select(reign_start) %>% 
  ymd(start_year) `    . Here emperors contain the data set

Comment: Interesting error. It is likely that ymd takes the unlisted values of reign_start (as numerals), which rightly gives negative value. See `emperors %>% select(reign_start) %>% unlist` . Anyway, @neifws has given the explanation for usage of `ymd`, namely to convert a string object into a date object. That is kind of out of the point in your example here, as your `reign_start` is clearly a date object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ymd()` is for converting character representations of dates into variables of class `Date` with format `YYYY-MM-DD`. Your dates are already of class `Date`.

The `lubridate` function you want is `year()`. I'm not sure how that handles BC dates but I assume you would like `0026-01-16` to return `26`.

So try `year(reign_start)`. Here are some examples which do require `ymd()` first (your data doesn't).

```
library(lubridate)
year(ymd("0026-01-16"))

[1] 26

# do we set year negative for BC? also works
year(ymd("-0026-01-16"))

[1] 26
```

Comment: I was wondering about BC as well, and apparently there is a [gregorian package](https://github.com/edgararuiz/gregorian) that seems to be addressing this. Also interesting to note how lubridate::ymd and as.Date handle negative years differently.